# PostgreSQL json: Query a value from different keys in a set

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I'm trying to query a value from a jsonb field in a table, but the value is located under a different key name in different records. (Unfortunately the JSON schema is not 100% consistent between records..)

Is there any function to, say, return the only non-null result from a list of expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `coalesce()`.  I don't know what the JSON looks like, but the general form is:

```
select coalesce(<exp1>, <exp2>, . . . )
```

This returns the first non-NULL expression.  The expression can be a JSON extract function.